# How to automatically transfer files from Windows to Mac after file change?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, react-native, macos-sierra

I'm writing a React Native Project in my Windows PC, and I have a Mac on the same network with my Windows PC, I want to automatically transfer the changes in code I make on my Windows machine to my Mac, so I can test it on iOs simulator.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Why not share your Windows development area with your Mac then it will always see the latest files without needing to move or copy anything?

Comment: I didn't know it's possible, Thanks.

Comment: Oh, ok. Right click on the folder in Windows that you want to share to the Mac and share it. On the Mac, start Finder and hit “Cmd K” and browse available shares.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell, it works like a charm.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project!